# mDNS not working between VirtualBox guests

Tags: virtualbox, bridge, mdns

I have two Linux guests (call them `db1` and `db2`, both [SL7](https://www.scientificlinux.org/)) running on a Fedora 25 host using [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/).  Both guests' network adapters are bridged to the host's wireless card.  Both guests have avahi running, and mDNS opened up in their firewalls.  All three machines (`db1`, `db2`, and `host`) have 192.168.4.x IP addresses from DHCP.

mDNS works great from the host.  The following all work fine:

```
[me@host ~]$ ssh db1.local
[me@host ~]$ ssh db2.local
[me@host ~]$ ping db1.local
[me@host ~]$ ping db2.local
```

But mDNS does not work to resolve one guest's name from the other guest.  For example:

```
[me@db1 ~]$ ping db2.local
ping: db2.local: Name or service not known
```

And vice-versa:

```
[me@db2 ~]$ ping db1.local
ping: db1.local: Name or service not known
```

What can I do to get those working?